# titanium using borderRadius setting with imageView

Tags: android, ios, titanium

i'd like the imageView "image" property to have a border around it. However, on the android system, this doesn't work - at least, not in the developer view-thingy.

What happens is the image shows up, no border. I think it is somehow sitting "on top" of the border... is there some way to set a border on an imageView image?

And no, i don't necessarily control the image... so i cannot just manually add a border to it!
Also, i mean:

```
var theImage = Ti.UI.createimageView({
    borderRadius: 5,
    ....
});
theImage.image = "xyz";
```

where, in the above scenario the borderRadius isn't being observed!

Answer (score 2):

This is working on only full ImageView covering image.

This is not working on image  property in imageView Object

This is working on backgroundImage Property

you try this code this is ofcourse working (truly)

```
var theImage = Ti.UI.createimageView({
    borderRadius: 5,
    ....
});

theImage.backgroundImage = "xyz.jpg";
```

Try This N enjoy Titanium SDK... Cheers...

Comment: i appreciate the effort, but i honestly don't understand what you're trying to say. The borderRadius value doesn't work when applied to an imageView, the image ignores it and creeps over the border

Answer (score 0):

Are you defining the `borderWidth` property?

If so, the image probably is sitting on the border.  So instead just try and add `theImage` to another view with the rounded borders like this:

```
var theImageContainer = Ti.UI.createView({
    borderColor  : 'red',
    borderRadius  : 5
    borderWidth : 3
    ... Positioning and size stuff etc...
});

theImageContainer.add(theImage);
```

Kind of a hack but this may be a bug with titanium.

Comment: hmm, no, this doesn't work. It does *add* a border - at least, a visible red border - but the border itself is "overwritten" by the image. 
What i mean is, any time the image itself defines (i'm using a transparent png in testing) anything that appears on the border, this appears instead of the red outline. As a result, my top right and left edges and bordered - but not the bottom right and left edge (because there is non transparent image there!)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe newer SDKs resolved this in the meantime. But I'd suggest to wrap the image with a view and to apply the border to the wrapper. Something like this:

```
var wrapper = Ti.UI.createView({
     width: Ti.UI.SIZE, 
     height: Ti.UI.SIZE, 
     borderRadius: 5, 
     borderWidth: 2, 
     borderColor: 'red',
});
var img = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image: '...',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
});
wrapper.add(img);
```